# Disable proxy service creation access wso2ei

Tags: wso2, enterprise-integration

Would anyone know how to disable the access to create and delete proxy, from a user, in wso2ei?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a particular role which only have permission to access the proxy (Not manage permissions) and assign that role to all the users who just need to access the proxy. You can refer to Admin guide on how to create roles and assign permissions.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Configuring+Roles

Comment: First off all, thank you from your help Thusitha. However, i tried to do that and create a role without any permission, but even so he was able to delete and create proxies. The best scenarious would be if the user couldn't even enter in management console, and just secure the proxy.

Comment: I found a alternative way to solve my problem. I went in the archieve 'mgt-user-xml' and changed the value between tag <EveryOneRoleName>, of everyone to admin, and the only user to have access started to be the admin. Just like i wanted. Thank you from your help Thusitha.

Answer (score 0):

Follow print exemplifying what I just did:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]